# pasar varios parámetros en una sola cadena a un IN MYSQL C#

Tags: mysql, c#, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, where

Quiero mandar una cadena asi :
'string cadena ="MTTO,DOC,INT";'

y esto se van recibir en una variable en Mysql Llama CONCEPTO.
Como muestro en la siguiente Consulta.

```
        select t.id_Cuenta,cl.Nombre_Completo,
        round(sum(t.Importe),2) as Salto ,round(sum(t.Importe*PORCENTAJE),2) as Intereses,
        round(sum(t.Importe),2) + round(sum(t.Importe*PORCENTAJE),2) as Total
        from cuenta c left join t1 t on c.id_Cuenta=t.id_Cuenta
        inner join cliente cl on c.id_Cliente=cl.idCliente
        where c.status=1 and t.Clave in (CONCEPTO) and t.Importe > 1 
        group by c.id_Cuenta order by c.id_Cuenta;
```

Me sirve si envio solo uno asi string cadena="'MTTO'";
pero si agrego mas de una cadena, string cadena="MTTO,DOC"; ya no me devuelve nada la consulta.
y acupo mandarlo asi por que es para N conceptos puede ser 1 o pueden ser 10 Conceptos los que envie. Alguien que pueda ayudarme.

Comment: La variable CONCEPTO  sería entonces una cadena, pero WHERE IN necesita una **lista** de valores.

Comment: Agregar a la pregunta el código para ejecutar la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la **función** **locate** la cual devuelve la primera ocurrencia de la subcadena pasada como parámetro, la misma recibe dos parámetros, el primero es la subcadena a buscar dentro de la cadena y el segundo la cadena.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
select t.id_Cuenta,cl.Nombre_Completo,
       reunido(sum(t.Importe),2) as Salto ,round(sum(t.Importe*PORCENTAJE),2) as Intereses,
       round(sum(t.Importe),2) + round(sum(t.Importe*PORCENTAJE),2) as Total
from cuenta c left join t1 t on c.id_Cuenta=t.id_Cuenta
inner join cliente cl on c.id_Cliente=cl.idCliente
where c.status=1 and locate(t.Clave, CONCEPTO) > 0 and t.Importe > 1 
group by c.id_Cuenta 
order by c.id_Cuenta;
```

Otra función que puede servirte es **instr**.

Revisa la siguiente **referencia** para mayor información:

https://thispointer.com/mysql-string-contains-query/